# Widget Screen Locked

Tags: plugins, dashboard

Within the Wordpress dashboard, the widget screen is locked and it won't allow me to drag new widgets within the sidebars - or remove any that's there. I've seen suggestions to toggle the 'screen options' from that page, but there that button is locked as well within that page in the dashboard. I've tried deactivated plugins and installing a 'cache clear' and still nothing.

**Anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening?**

Comment: What do you mean by locked? As in the js isn't working?

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser? A different computer? These will help narrow down the issue to being browser-related or server-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like something is breaking your javascript. Install/Open Firebug (if using firefox) and check the console for JavaScript errors then debug from there. It's probably a plugin loading some conflicting JS. The other thing I've seen do this is loading jQuery from Google CDN in the backend. So if your theme is using the fairly common snippet to de-register jQuery then re-register it from google CDN it should only do so on the frontend.